# Which reason in GPG for revoking key should I choose?

Tags: certificate, gnupg, gpg4win

I want to generate revocation certificate for my GPG key, print it out and keep securely in closed envelope up till I'll loose access to this key (accidental removal/pen drive loss/theft).

Which reason should I choose in GPG while generating it? **Key has been compromised** or **key is no longer used**?

Or even should I generate more revocation certificates for multiple situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you physically lose the key, then you must assume that somebody else has it. Therefore, the key would be considered **compromised** and you should indicate that in the revocation information.

You would use "key is no longer used" if you retired the application that was using it, or if you decided to switch to a different key/program/scheme. Since all revocation certificates do the same thing (make your key no longer valid), it's not a big deal if you don't include the specific reason for revocation. Also, if you're retiring the key gracefully, you can just make the certificate right then.

It is, of course, really important that you always have access to *a* revocation certificate in case the key needs to be invalidated.

Comment: So I should create two revocation keys, one for situation when I loose access to the media (key compromised) and one for accidental removal done by me or pen drive destruction (key is no longer used). Shouldn't I?

Comment: @ZiemekZabawa You could, but all revocation certificates do the same thing. It wouldn't hurt to have multiple. (I've updated my answer.)

Comment: Thank you for answer  For normal moving from old key to new one I use "key is superseded" and give new key ID in description.